# how to restart interactive program with psremoting powershell?

Tags: powershell

My Background is in unix admin, so I'm applying my unix methodology to admin tasks in windows (which is possibly a mistake)

We have an interactive program that is effectively a service.  I just learnt that services are different from regular programs, unlike unix.

The systems start with automatic login and start the program at login.  However like long running services they need to be occasionally restarted.

This usually involved teamviewer and task manager and clicking an icon on the desktop, long winded, prone to mistakes and requires admin users with the correct knowledge.

I was hoping to automate this task using Powershell and psremoting.  I've been able to stop the process easily but restarting it is a problem.   I've now learnt something about session 0 vs session 1.  Every article I've read says that this is not recommended and no longer possible, to start an interactive program from a service.

I've looked at creating my own service, using psexec, using start-process with the local users credentials, but nothing seems to work.

I've never had this sort of issue on a unix machine and I'm wondering how windows deals with this scenario?

Thanks heaps
Mark